# gVim closes automatically when opening python file

Tags: vim, python, gvim, vim-plugins

I'm using gVim 7.4 , it was running smoothly before installing Plugins after installing **pathogen** gVim window closes automatically when opening python files.
It's working fine for other files except Python. When i installed **Pathogen** the same problem occurred. Now i installed **python-mode** manually due to the problem but still i'm facing the problem.

I installed both **omnicppcomplete** and **python-mode**.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins also interact with the libraries in your system. The first thing to try is to launch gVim in the terminal (just type gvim there) and note the message. It may tell you which library has problem - try to reinstall it.

Comment: There's no problem in opening like dat. the only Problem is with python files.

Comment: What do you get printed if open gvim like `strace gvim somefile.py` (assuming that you are using Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't a crash, but some command like `:quit` that automatically closes Vim, try to capture a log with `vim -V20vimlog`, and inspect the last commands executed.

Answer (score 0):

I've disabled all the plugins and installed **pydiction** and **omnicppcomplete** it's working fine now even though i don't know the reason of closing it automatically.

I think it's related to the plugin.